# Grabbing the nearest uppermost-parallel value of another column under X conditions

Tags: google-sheets

Objective: Write an array formula inside a column that outputs the nearest uppermost-parallel value from other column under the condition that a different column is set to a specific value.

See [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B1IPxPLHI2ISCeD0aWCXP_8QrYecrTbkEEAWuegJNPk/edit#gid=1949960648) and image below for example inputs and outputs. If the image fails to open, it is also inside the Sheet in "Image" tab.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
={"formula_";index(if((B5:B="Parent")+(B5:B=""),,scan(,A5:A,lambda(a,c,if(c="",a,c)))))}
```

[image]