# Grabbing the nearest uppermost-parallel value of another column if other column equals X

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This question has been [asked before for Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76649171/grabbing-the-nearest-uppermost-parallel-value-of-another-column-under-x-conditio), but now asking for Excel solution.

Objective: Write an array formula inside a column that outputs the nearest uppermost-parallel value from other column under the condition that a different column is set to a specific value.

See [sheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ApYx4AGhwQsDj0WHkrAPYHKV-xAW?e=SeLp2z) and image below for example inputs and outputs. If the image fails to open, it is also inside "Image" tab of the workbook.

[image]

As a reference, the Google Sheets version of the formula is also in the sheet, but it only works in Google Sheets. Here is the Google Sheets version of the solution.

```
=index(if((B5:B="Parent")+(B5:B=""),,scan(,A5:A,lambda(a,c,if(c="",a,c)))))
```

For this excel sheet, the formula needs to be written in the form of a single-cell formula that processes down the whole column (without having to drag-fill) similar to a Google Sheets Array Formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     x,MATCH(7^89,1/(B:B<>"")),
     y,A5:INDEX(A:A,x),
     z,B5:INDEX(B:B,x),
     IF((z="")+(z="Parent"),z,SCAN(,y,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b="",a,b)))))
```